# Trouble configuring a spring bean to accept a mule message or event

Tags: java, spring, mule

Using Mule 3.2.1, I want to pass a Mule Message or Mule Event to an object configured as a spring:bean.  For example:

```
<spring:bean id="myId" class="com.address.className"/>
...
<flow name="flowName">
    <component>
        <spring-object bean="myId"/>
    </component>
</flow>
```

'className' looks like this:

```
public class className implements MessageProcessor {
    @Override
    public MuleEvent process(MuleEvent event) throws MuleException {...}
}
```

The process method is never called though, and there are no errors in the mule log.  What am I missing to get my bean to receive the Mule data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `<custom-processor class="com.address.className" />` instead.

More info:

http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/Routing+Message+Processors#RoutingMessageProcessors-CustomProcessor

http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/Custom+Message+Processors

Answer (score 0):

`custom-processor` will not let you use spring beans, it will create a new instance. You can use `processor` instead of `component` or `custom-processor`:

```
<spring:bean id="myId" class="com.address.className"/>
...
<flow name="flowName">
     <processor ref="myId" />
</flow>
```